# How to send messages from flask to a browser immediately

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

In my flask app I'm prompting a user to enter numbers manually in the terminal. Those numbers are then sent to the browser to update the DOM. But the problem is that the DOM is updated after function `getInputs` is completed even though I emit an event after each user's input. So my expectation was the DOM gets updated immediately after the event was emitted (inside the `getInput` function). What I want is: user enters the first number -> append it to the DOM, user enters the second number -> append it to the DOM. How to do this? Should I refactor my code somehow?

This is my flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '#secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('message was received!!!')


@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received my event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)


@socketio.on('get inputs')
def get_inputs():
    getInput(prompt="First number: ")
    getInput(prompt="Second number: ")


def getInput(prompt = "Enter number: "):
    x = input(prompt)
    socketio.emit('my response', {"number": x})
    return x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <button id="btnGetInputs">Get inputs</button>
    <ul id="log">
        <!-- append elements here -->
    </ul>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
        var numbers = []

        socket.on('connect', function () {
            socket.emit('my event', {
                data: 'User Connected'
            })
            $("#btnGetInputs").click(function () {
                socket.emit("get inputs")
            })
        })

        socket.on('my response', function (msg) {
            console.log(msg)
            if (msg.number) {
                numbers.push(msg.number)
                items = ''
                for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    items = items + '<li>' + numbers[i].toString() + '</li>'
                }
                $('#log').html(items);
            }
        })

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What async mode are you using for your Flask-SocketIO server? For this type of application only "threading" is going to work, because your getInput calls are blocking on all other async frameworks.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. Can you guide me where to look for code samples to implement threading? I'm not an expert in flask.